# In Python how to modify an outer attribute from an inner function?

Tags: python

```
class Bike(object):
    def __init__(self,Name,StatusFrontWheel,StatusRearWheel):
        self.name = Name
        self.Status='OK'
        self.FrontWheel = self.Wheel(StatusFrontWheel)
        self.RearWheel = self.Wheel(StatusRearWheel)
 
    def show(self):
        print('In outer class')
        print('Name:', self.name)
        print('Status:', self.Etat)
        
    class Wheel(object):
        def __init__(self,WheelStatus):
            self.WheelStatus = WheelStatus
 
        def puncture(self):
            self.WheelStatus='NOK'
            # how to change Bike.self.status to 'NOK'?
            Bike.Status='NOK'
```

Let say I create an outer `Bike` class with an inner class for wheel. And in the outer init, I instantiate the Front and rear wheel from the inner class. And if there is a puncture (here a method), I want my bike instance status to be changed to NOK

```py
Bike1=Bike('MyBike1','OK','OK')
Bike2=Bike('MyBike2','OK','OK')
print(Bike2.FrontWheel.WheelStatus)  # gives 'OK'

Bike2.FrontWheel.puncture()   # so here the puncture occurred

print(Bike2.Status)    # gives me 'OK'
```

but `print(Bike.Status)` gives me NOK

Comment: Wheel should be outside of Bike. Bike should take two wheels as input. I’ve never seen anyone nest class definitions like this in 15 years of writing python. The Bike class you have a method that checks each tire before determining if the bike itself is ok. This is a longer-term approach as bikes can have chains break, frames can crack, derailleur hangers can be bent, etc.

Comment: Instantiating a `Wheel` does not make that instance know who instantiated it. The line `Bike.Status='NOK'` creates a new class attribute on `Bike`.

Comment: Also, wheels can be swapped between bikes. You if you defined the Wheel class outside of bike, you could associate one wheel with multiple bikes. You could also set this up so bikes could have multiple sets of wheel, but at that point we’re modeling my life and not your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`Wheel` class doesn't contain any reference to `Bike` it is a part of, so it cannot back-propagate its status to this Bike.

What can you do instead is to make Bike's status a property, dynamically calculated based on current status of both wheels.

The class also doesn't realy need to be nested, and I've changed naming to follow commonly accepted convention.

```
class Bike(object):
    def __init__(self,name,status_front_wheel,status_rear_wheel):
        self.name = name
        self.front_wheel = Wheel(status_front_wheel)
        self.rear_wheel = Wheel(status_rear_wheel)
 
    def show(self):
        print('In outer class')
        print('Name:', self.name)
        print('Status:', self.status)

    @property
    def status(self):
        if self.front_wheel.status == "OK" and self.front_wheel.status == "OK":
            return "OK"
        else:
            return "NOK"
        
class Wheel(object):
    def __init__(self, status):
        self.status = status

    def puncture(self):
        self.status='NOK'
```

This way `Wheel`s only need to care about their own status, and the Bike will handle checking if its components verify the needs of the entire bike.

Comment: thank-you for your code, it works fine (just a small typo in the def status function  where the front_wheel is used twice. I've added a repaired function in the Wheel class, and if the two wheels of a bike instance are punctured, and if only one wheel is repaired, the status of the bike is still NOK (which is normal as the other tire is still flat)

Answer (score 0):

Okay there are a few glaring issues here. First, you should not be nesting classes. Here is a better implementation which works:

```
class Bike(object):
    def __init__(self, name, front_tyre_status="OK", rear_tyre_status="OK"):
        self.name = name
        self.Status = 'OK'
        self.FrontWheel = Wheel(self)
        self.RearWheel = Wheel(self)

    def show(self):
        print('In outer class')
        print('Name:', self.name)
        print('Status:', self.Status)


class Wheel(object):

    def __init__(self, bike, status="OK"):
        self.bike = bike
        self.WheelStatus = status

    def puncture(self):
        print("punctured!")
        self.WheelStatus = 'NOK'
        self.bike.Status = 'NOK'
```

Answer (score 0):

As comment suggested, you should not have the class Wheel inside of the function, but if you need to make this work, try:

```
self.FrontWheel = self.Wheel(StatusFrontWheel, self)
self.RearWheel = self.Wheel(StatusRearWheel, self)
```

Add an extra parameter to the `Wheel` class `__init__` and lastly:
Add this to the `puncture` method:

```
self.bike_instance.Status = 'NOK'
```